# How do I make a git server accessible to multiple users?

Tags: permissions, git

I have set up a git server, but I'm having some problems with users pushing their commits. I have a total of 3 users, but if any one of them pushes some files, they become read-only for the other users, and the unpacker fails if they try to push.

I can temporarily fix this issue by recursively setting all permissions to `777` but that is a terrible approach and only fixes it until the next push.

How can I make it so that all selected users can both push and pull, without having to change permissions every single time?

Answer (score 1):

Create your repository [with `git init --shared`, which will](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#git-init---sharedfalsetrueumaskgroupallworldeverybody0xxx):

> Specify that the Git repository is to be shared amongst several users. This allows users belonging to the same group to push into that repository. When specified, the config variable "core.sharedRepository" is set so that files and directories under `$GIT_DIR` are created with the requested permissions.

Put all the users who should have write access into the same group, and Git (including the various SSH and smart server elements) will create the files group-writable and `g+sx`. You may want to create a special group to use for that and `chgrp -R` the repository to it.

This will also enable the `receive.denyNonFastForwards` setting on the repository, which you can disable manually if required.

Comment: All the users are in the `git` group, the permissions bits are `g+sx` on all files, but pushing still fials with: `Already up-to-date.

Pushing to mariusz@CENSORED:/srv/git/website.git
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects        
remote: fatal: failed to write object        
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To mariusz@CENSORED:/srv/git/website.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'mariusz@CENSORED:/srv/git/website.git'
`

Comment: Create the repository in the first place with `--shared`, don't try to fake it. It does a bit of work behind the scenes.

Comment: So the only option is to re-create it?

Comment: It's not the *only* option, of course, but it's the sensible one. It's git, all copies are the same, you don't lose anything.